# Why warning directive in C throws LINT error?

Tags: c, lint, pc-lint

I am using GNU C and IAR compilers with my ARM Cortex M projects using MCUXpresso IDE. I am using PC-LINT checker.

Under IAR compiler I have a problem with #warning directive throwing two LINT errors

```
#warning Dont compile it in RELEASE //example directive

LINT: 10: Expecting end of line //throwed lint errors
LINT: 16: Unrecognized name
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The `#warning` directive is not  GCC standard C. It is an extension, albeit a very common one.

Comment: I would like to still use this directive. I wonder if there is a way to fix LINT errors?

Comment: Apologies for not observing that my iPhone is hung up on throwing random acronyms like GCC and BBC into my typing for no good reason that I can spot (and being in too much of a hurry to post a comment — mostly because I was concentrating on typing and not reading what the spell-mangler on the phone makes of my typing).  I meant "is not standard C", of course (it is a GCC extension).  That's confusing.

Comment: As to the "how to fix it", I don't use PC-Lint.  It seems unlikely to me that it cannot handle (accept) `#warning` directives, but I've no idea how to suppress the complaint.  I'd have to manual bash for an answer, starting off with finding the manual.  I would expect it is possible; I don't know that it is possible.  It depends in part on PC-Lint's attitude towards things not strictly standard.  If it always complins about anything, you may be stuck.  If it can be persuaded some things are OK, there is probably a way around it.

Comment: A manual from 2001 says: _13.5 **User-Defined Keywords** PC-lint/FlexeLint might stumble over strange preprocessor commands that your compiler happens to support. For example, some Unix system compilers support `#ident`. Since this is something that can NOT be handled by a suitable `#define` of some identifier we have added the `+ppw(command-name)` option ('ppw'
is an abbreviation for PreProcessor Word). For example, `+ppw(ident)` will add the preprocessor command alluded to above. PC-lint/FlexeLint recognizes and ignores the construct._ Also consider `#ifndef _lint` / `#warning … / `#endif`.

Comment: Which version of PC Lint are you using? The seasoned PC Lint v9.00 or the newer PC Lint Plus?